# Highlighting a row in GridView contron in winforms depending on a value in a specified column

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview

I am trying to highlight an entire row in WinForms Gridview using C# if a value in a column matches
a specified string value:

I am using:

```
 private void dataGridView1_RowPrePaint(object sender, DataGridViewRowPrePaintEventArgs e)
        {
           
               
            if (Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[5]).Contains("Product charges"))
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Beige;
            }

        }
```

but it is not working.

I also tried:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
                {
                    if ((Convert.ToString(cell.Value) == "Product charges"))
                    {
                        row.InheritedStyle.BackColor = Color.BlueViolet;
                    } 
                }
            }
```

and I tried:

```
private void dataGridView1_RowPrePaint(object sender, DataGridViewRowPrePaintEventArgs e)
        {


            //if (Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[5]).Contains("Product charges"))
            //{
            //    dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Beige;
            //}

            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
                {
                    if ((Convert.ToString(cell.Value).Contains("Product charges")))
                    {
                        row.InheritedStyle.BackColor = Color.BlueViolet;
                    } 
                }
            }

        }
```

I know I am missing something simple.

Comment: If you set a breakpoint in the `If` condition block, is it ever hit? Also, use the Column name instead of the index (as `dataGridView1["ColumnName", e.RowIndex].Value.ToString()` instead of  `dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[5]` <- there's no `.Value` here, you're converting to string the Cell object). You should also add a check `if (e.RowIndex == dataGridView1.NewRowIndex) return;`

Answer (score 0):

```
  foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
            {
                if ((Convert.ToString(cell.Value).Contains("2")))
                {
                    row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.BlueViolet;
                }
            }
        }
```

This should work for you,

check the below condition is satisficed in you code

```
 if ((Convert.ToString(cell.Value).Contains("Product charges")))
```

Comment: Can you indicate a value in a particular column?